# self.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE not activating quick enough.. any work around?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, collision, user-interaction

I have a collision handler detecting for a game over situation, however when the rocket lands (else if), the labels become visible no problems, but there is a second where the touch down even still registers, then the rocket takes off again, then the touch disables. Is there any obvious thing I'm doing wrong?

```
-(BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionPreSolve:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair rocket:(CCNode *)nodeA landingPad:(CCNode *)nodeB{
//if travelling too fast on landing..
if (_rocket.physicsBody.velocity.y < maximumVerticalVelocity){
    _crashNotice.visible = TRUE;
     crashed = TRUE;
    [_rocket removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
    self.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;

}else if (_rocket.physicsBody.velocity.y > 0.01){
    self.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;

    //show game won state
    _scoreLabel.visible = FALSE;
    _showScoreLabel.visible = TRUE;

}return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: What's `self`? userInteractionEnabled on Apple classes is instant. If you're seeing interaction allowed again, something else is re-enabling it.

Comment: This is the gameplay.m file. The only userInteractionEnabled = TRUE; statement is in the didLoadFromCCB method. Could it be coming from there?

Comment: what are FALSE and TRUE? In Objc you ought to be using YES and NO.

Comment: Echoing @LearnCocos2D use YES and No not TRUE and FALSE. Also, the only way this could be taking a while to perform is if it was possibly on a background thread? Could this be the case?

Comment: Fixed, but thanks for the heads up on true false, yes and no. Is there any actual difference because both seem to work the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of enable and disable touch, handle through bool value.

In class.h file declare this

```
 bool mAllowTouch;
```

In Init/onEnter :

```
-(void)onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];

    mAllowTouch = true;
    self.userInteractionEnabled = true;
}
```

In your function

```
-(BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionPreSolve
{
       if(YOUR_CONDITION_TO_STOP_TOUCH)
       {
          mAllowTouch = false;
       }
       else 
       {
           mAllowTouch = true;
      }
}
```

In touch function, use mAllowTouch to process your touch.

```
-(void) touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    if(mAllowTouch)
    { 
         //handle touch here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! I also had to add a mAllowTouch check on the method being called by the touchBegan to get this to work, but works like a charm. Cheers.